# Versatility of IExecuteCommand vs. IContextMenu

Tags: c++, winapi, com, windows-shell

Following the *"classic"* **`IContextMenu`** way of creating context menu shell extensions, it's possible to **associate an image** to each of the new custom menu items.
In fact, in `IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu()` implementation, it's possible to call `SetMenuItemBitmaps()` API to set the bitmap for the custom menu item.

Moreover, using **`IContextMenu3::HandleMenuMsg2()`**, it's possible to respond to `WM_MEASUREITEM` and `WM_DRAWITEM` shell messages, to implement some custom **owner drawing**.

Does the new Windows 7+ **`IExecuteCommand`** interface allow this versatility?
Using this interface, is it possible to set custom images for menu items, and do some owner drawing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See "[Simplifying context menu extensions with IExecuteCommand](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100312-01/?p=14623)". As I understand, it's not a replacement for `IContextMenu` et al. If you need fancy UI features available with `IContextMenu`, keep using it. If you don't, `IExecuteCommand` is easier to implement.

Comment: @EchoLynx: Thanks for the heads up on the link. I edited the answer to use the updated link you provided.